# Storing sessions in an ios application

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm Using an application that the user can register and after activating his account from my side, he can login and have more features.

The problem now is do i Use `NSUserDefaults` as a session handler so when the user login he won't login again until he remove the application and install it again or how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is good option. user can login and logout multiple time using this. you just need to save object/ value for key when user login and delete the same when user will logout.

```
NSString *value = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"anyKeyName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to get value

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"anyKeyName"];
```

When user will logout, just remove that key

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"anyKeyName"];
```

or set `nil` to that value if you don't want to delete your key.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"anyKeyName"];
```

**but I will prefer** `removeObjectForKey`.